# Strange value in LINQ query result

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

In my application on reports page I have more that one filter (start date, end date, payment type ...etc) and I want to generate a query depending on user selection as following:

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (cboPaymentType.SelectedItem != null)
            _selectedPaymentId = ((PaymentType)cboPaymentType.SelectedItem).id;

        _dateFrom = dpInvoiceFrom.SelectedDate;
        _dateTo = dpInvoiceTo.SelectedDate;

        IQueryable<invoice> invoicesQuery = _context.invoices;

        if (_selectedPaymentId != 0)
            invoicesQuery = invoicesQuery.Where(s => s.payment_id == _selectedPaymentId);

        if (_dateFrom != null)
            invoicesQuery = invoicesQuery.Where(s => s.invoice_date >= _dateFrom);

        if (_dateTo != null)
            invoicesQuery = invoicesQuery.Where(s => s.invoice_date <= _dateTo);

        ocInvoices = new ObservableCollection<invoice>(invoicesQuery);
    }
```

The result always nothing !!, When I check the query result I found strange value `@p__linq__0` in WHERE clause:

```
WHERE ([Extent1].[invoice_date] >= @p__linq__0)
```

What Is my mistake ?

Comment: That is a variable name, and there is nothing strange about it. Your C# variable _dateFrom is called @p__linq__0 in SQL. That's normal. Without seeing your data, nobody can check, if there are any records, that should match your search criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Even tho it shouldn't make a difference you probably want to materialize query first before passing to constructor.

```
ocInvoices = new ObservableCollection<invoice>(invoicesQuery.AsEnumerable());
```

or

```
ocInvoices = new ObservableCollection<invoice>(invoicesQuery.ToList());
```

According to a strange value `@p__linq__0`. It is query parameter which is part of the generated SQL query.

```
DECLARE @p__linq__0 datetime = {value from local variable};

SELECT
    ...
FROM ...
WHERE ([Extent1].[invoice_date] >= @p__linq__0)
```

In general the problem might be that you have no rows that satisfy conditions, thus you get empty result.